# What data structure and algorithm to organize rectangles in 2D space without overlap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, 2d

I need to use rectangle to represent an item in my app and allow users to rearrange it to anywhere by doing drag and drop. The app needs to be able to automatically add one rectangle next to the others, adjust others if one is removed, tell which is next to which. There shouldn't be any overlapping between rectangles. While dragging around, it should help users snapping to the closest item.

With all these features in mind, what data structure is best for my items? These seem pretty common features in a lot of GUI apps.

My current solution is put all of them in a list, use bounding box info to add item to a reasonable position next to the whole boundingbox. After remove an item, recalculate the whole boundingbox. The tricky part is when users drag an item around or delete an item, how do I reorganize the rest items to keep them in a reasonable layout?

Comment: How many total objects are you expecting to work with? For a small number, what you're describing sounds pretty reasonable.

Comment: It's a small number, but I can't figure out how to deal with reorgnanize if one is removed or dragged to another place.